# How to return compressed data from API to the browser, and uncompress them?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-web-api, compression

I'm creating a Web API using ASP.NET MVC.
In some cases, the data requested by the browser may be large (up to 5MB) and I'd like to compress it to speed up the process and reduce the bandwith.

Here is my endpoint :

```
[RoutePrefix("Api/MyRoute")]
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        /* Simplified for clarity */

        var data = businessLayer.FindRequiredDataFromDB()
        return Ok(data);
    }
}
```

This works, but the amount of data is sometimes big :

[image: Uncompressed data]

In order to compress data, I created an `ActionFilter` to GZip the content :

```
public class CompressAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actContext)
    {
        var content = actContext.Response.Content;
        var bytes = content == null ? null : content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
        var zlibbedContent = bytes == null ? new byte[0] :
        CompressionHelper.DeflateByte(bytes);
        actContext.Response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(zlibbedContent);
        actContext.Response.Content.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
        actContext.Response.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip"); /* Is that OK ? */
        actContext.Response.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"); /* Same here ? */
        base.OnActionExecuted(actContext);
    }
}

public class CompressionHelper
{
    public static byte[] DeflateByte(byte[] str)
    {
        if (str == null)
            return null;

        using (var output = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (
                var compressor = new Ionic.Zlib.GZipStream(
                    output, Ionic.Zlib.CompressionMode.Compress,
                    Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestSpeed)
                  )
            {
                compressor.Write(str, 0, str.Length);
            }

            return output.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Then decorate my API Endpoint like that :

```
[Compress]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    //...
}
```

Then, when I call this same endpoint with Postman (very same request) :

[image: GZipped compression]

**So it seems OK in Postman :)**
(size is reduced, time is longer because of a forgotten breakpoint during PrintScreen, please ignore it)

**However**, when called it in another app :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("CallAPI", "Search")",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ /*...*/ }),
    contentType: 'application/json',
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data); /* See result below */
});
```

Controller :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> CallAPI(/**/)
{
    /* Simplified logic for clarity */

    var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
    var request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage()
            {
                RequestUri = new Uri(endPointURL),
                Method = System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get
            };

    var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
    var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return new HttpStatusContentResult(data, HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Result send to the browser looks like this :

[image: Compressed data]

Compressed yeah, but not readable...

I tried to unzip this content in browser using [Pako](https://nodeca.github.io/pako/) or other JS libraries, I can' get it work.
I'm new with APIs, did I forget something ? Could someone point me out where I'm wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: Have you turned on the gzip compression built into web browsers? https://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/

Comment: I'm using IISExpress in Dev. I just added this line in `%PROGRAMFILES%\IIS Express\applicationhost.config` : `<mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json"/>` in `<httpCompression> \ <dynamicTypes>`. Then restart. But same result :(

Comment: Did you read the article I linked? If the request has a Content-Encoding: gzip, then the result should be encoded with gzip, which means the content over the wire is compressed.

Comment: I expected my result should be encoded with gzip using `actContext.Response.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");`. So the content is compressed but it should be decoded client-side to be treated, isn't it ?

Comment: It's the request that needs to ask for gzip (content-encoding: gzip).  IIS should automatically see that and do the compression.  I don't think it's something you need to code.